# Adding a join to a count() query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following code taken from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063488/merging-sql-queries) and changed a little.

```
SELECT *
FROM ES_TOOL
  INNER JOIN ES_HARDWARE ON ES_HARDWARE.eshw_ID = ES_TOOL.ESTOOL_HARDWARE 
  INNER JOIN ES_PAYMENT  on ES_payment.espay_id = es_TOOL.estool_payment 

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      tchap.estch_tool, tfacet.estfa_tool,
      count(marks.esmrk_value) AmtMarks 
    FROM ES_MARK marks 
      left Join ES_TOOL_FACET tfacet ON marks.esmark_tool_facet = tfacet.estfa_id --line added
      left Join ES_TOOL_CHAPTER tchap ON marks.esmark_tool_chapter = tchap.estch_id 
    GROUP BY tchap.estch_tool 
  ) h  ON ES_TOOL.estool_id = h.estch_tool
```

I'm trying to add an additional join in an attempt to get a mark count from "marks" that meet either of the left join "ON" criteria. Without the extra line the query executes, but doesn't count marks that match "facet" criteria. With it I get the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Column 'ES_TOOL_FACET.estfa_tool' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can include some example input and output data in your question it'll be easier to be specific about the answer.

Comment: Can `tchap.estch_tool` and `tfacet.estfa_tool` hold same values? If they can, should the same values' matches be counted together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution comes in two variants. Which one better suits you may depend on which one will yield the better execution plan when tried on your data.

Description of **variant #1**: (In both cases I am describing only the logic behind the main SELECT's LEFT JOIN subselect, the part that is actually becomes substituted. But the scripts come as complete queries, equivalent to yours):

1. Pull and UNION ALL the items from both `tools` tables.
2. Join the list against the `marks` table accordingly.
3. Group the result set by tool items and get the counts.

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ES_TOOL
  INNER JOIN ES_HARDWARE ON ES_HARDWARE.eshw_ID = ES_TOOL.ESTOOL_HARDWARE 
  INNER JOIN ES_PAYMENT  on ES_payment.espay_id = es_TOOL.estool_payment 

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      tools.tool,
      COUNT(*) AS AmtMarks
    FROM (
      SELECT 'tchap'  AS tbl, estch_id AS id, estch_tool AS tool
      FROM ES_TOOL_CHAPTER

      UNION ALL

      SELECT 'tfacet' AS tbl, estfa_id AS id, estfa_tool AS tool
      FROM ES_TOOL_FACET
    ) tools
      INNER JOIN ES_MARK marks
        ON tools.tbl = 'tchap'  AND tools.id = marks.esmark_tool_chapter
        OR tools.tbl = 'tfacet' AND tools.id = marks.esmark_tool_facet
    GROUP BY tools.tool
  ) h ON ES_TOOL.estool_id = h.tool
```

**Variant #2**:

1. Join `ES_TOOL_CHAPTER` against `marks` and get all the `estch_tool` values, including duplicates.
2. Similarly, join `ES_TOOL_FACET` against `marks` and get all the `estfa_tool` values, with duplicates too.
3. UNION ALL both sets.
4. Group the resulting set by tool items and get the counts.

And the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ES_TOOL
  INNER JOIN ES_HARDWARE ON ES_HARDWARE.eshw_ID = ES_TOOL.ESTOOL_HARDWARE 
  INNER JOIN ES_PAYMENT  on ES_payment.espay_id = es_TOOL.estool_payment 

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      tools.tool,
      COUNT(*) AS AmtMarks
    FROM (
      SELECT estch_tool AS tool
      FROM ES_TOOL_CHAPTER tools
        INNER JOIN ES_MARK marks ON tools.estch_id = marks.esmark_tool_chapter

      UNION ALL

      SELECT estfa_tool AS tool
      FROM ES_TOOL_FACET tools
        INNER JOIN ES_MARK marks ON tools.estfa_id = marks.esmark_tool_facet
    ) tools
    GROUP BY tools.tool
  ) h ON ES_TOOL.estool_id = h.tool
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that ES_TOOL_FACET.estfa_tool needs to be included in the Group By.

When you use Group By, all non-aggregated columns must be included in the group by section.

Answer (score 1):

This should be obvious, in your inner query:

```
SELECT  tchap.estch_tool, tfacet.estfa_tool,  count(marks.esmrk_value) AmtMarks 
FROM ES_MARK marks 
  left Join ES_TOOL_FACET tfacet ON marks.esmark_tool_facet = tfacet.estfa_id --line added
  left Join ES_TOOL_CHAPTER tchap ON marks.esmark_tool_chapter = tchap.estch_id 
GROUP BY tchap.estch_tool
```

you have three selected columns, `estch_tool` which is in the `GROUP BY` clause, `esmrk_value` which is in an aggregate function, and `estfa_tool` which is neither in the `GROUP BY` clause nor in an aggregate function.

Your solution should be either:

1. `GROUP BY tchap.estch_tool, tfacet.estfa_tool`
2. `AVG(tfacet.estfa_tool)` or any aggregate function

Comment: I tried: GROUP BY tchap.estch_tool, tfacet.estfa_tool , but then the query returns 2 lines for each tool with chapter and facet matches, whereas I need one line for each tool with a total count for both chapter and facet matches. Ideas?

Comment: Well, you'll have to debug your query then. Perhaps somewhere you have joined in a table which expands the result set by 2 (in that case you should be missing a WHERE clause)?  Ah, the fun of debugging and tuning SQL...

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in this query -

```
SELECT  
            tchap.estch_tool, 
            tfacet.estfa_tool,  
            count(marks.esmrk_value) AmtMarks 
        FROM ES_MARK marks   
            left Join ES_TOOL_FACET tfacet ON 
                marks.esmark_tool_facet = tfacet.estfa_id --line added  
            left Join ES_TOOL_CHAPTER tchap ON 
                marks.esmark_tool_chapter = tchap.estch_id  
        GROUP BY tchap.estch_tool
```

GROUP BY mandates that any column appearing in SELECT list should either be aggregated or appear in GROUP BY clause.

So put an aggregate function - MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG etc on tfacet.estfa_tool because it does not appear in group by clause or include it there.

Comment: oh my.. i am so slow at typing... there two answers already!!