# SQL select statement with either ( * ) or (fields names) which performs better?

Tags: sql-server, performance, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is faster/best? SELECT * or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
```

and

```
SELECT field1, field2,...... FROM tbl1
```

how does `SQL engine` execute the previous two select statements (step by step) and which one performs better?

Comment: @Rami: From a performance time perspective? or from an application design performance persepctive? Personally I thought the two variants were identical with respect to execution time. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Simen S: i originally asked this quest from performance time perspective, but now im asking for both :)

Comment: @Simen: not even close; check out Brent's explanation: http://vimeo.com/12510154  at timestamp 10:50

Comment: @p.campbell Yes, It certainly looks like a duplicate. And interestingly: the two appear *not* to be identical from a performance perspective (which I thought). huh! +1 for instantly recognizing the duplicate :-)

Comment: @Rami: the answer is clear all 'round: specify your columns, do not use `*` for anything other than your own ad-hoc queries.

Comment: @Simen: it's one of the most duplicated questions on StackOverflow; I had to choose only one! :) Dig into the answers and discussion on the other highest voted question: [Can Select * Ever Be Justified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635781/can-select-usage-ever-be-justified)

Comment: How about [Why Is Select * Considered Harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) OMG nailed it with his answer.

Comment: @p.campbell Lol: I really only started to "hang out" here a couple of days ago. I've seen som duplicates already, and will be prepared for thisone again. Has anyone at meta.stackoverflow ever suggested a duplicate detection during posting filter?

Comment: @Simen: indeed, try composing your own question on this topic. Dupes *are* shown to you as you compose your title, so the OP basically just ignored it, I suspect.

Comment: @p.campbell: really?! I'll look for that the next time I feel like asking. I've only asked one question. It has 14 views, 1 vote, no answers and sadly no duplicates. I Didn't recognize the duplicate detection feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: * is slow, named fields are fast.
Fewer named fields are faster.
Smaller datafields are faster than bigger ones.
Never select blobs of you do not have to.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in this old Answered post about:

[Select * vs Select Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In case of MySQL even a column order matters (and its order in table definition).