# SELECT * - pros /cons

Tags: sql, select

I always hear from SQL specialists that it is not efficient to use the '*' sign in SELECT statement and it is better to list all the field names instead.

But I don't find it efficient for me personally when it comes to adding new fields to a table and then updating all the stored procedures accordingly.

So what are the pros and cons in using '*' ?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can select \* usage ever be justified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635781/can-select-usage-ever-be-justified)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, the use of `SELECT *` is not a good idea.

Pros:

- When you add/remove columns, you don't have to make changes where you did use `SELECT *`
- It is shorter to write
- Also see the answers to: [Can select * usage ever be justified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635781/can-select-usage-ever-be-justified)

Cons:

- You are returning more data than you need. Say you add a `VARBINARY` column that contains 200k per row. You only need this data in **one** place for a single record - using `SELECT *` you can  end up returning 2MB per 10 rows *that you don't need*
- Explicit about what data is used
- Specifying columns means you get an error when a column is removed
- The query processor has to do some more work - figuring out what columns exist on the table (thanks [@vinodadhikary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637697/select-pros-cons/17637724#comment25681945_17637724))
- You can find where a column is used more easily
- You get all columns in joins if you use `SELECT *`
- You can't use ordinal referencing (though using ordinal references for columns is bad practice in itself)
- Also see the answers to: [What is the reason not to use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)

Comment: To add to the cons, the query processor has to figure out what columns exists in the particular table first.

Comment: @vinodadhikary - Why would that be more work than validating an explicit column list containing all column names? I'd imagine it might be slightly less work in fact as it just needs to retrieve all column metadata not validate each one individually.

Comment: @MartinSmith, The wild character `*` has to be expanded before all fields are validated.  So if the `select` contains an `*` that gets added to the field_list.  The optimization is minimal as far as performance is concerned but that extra function call is saved.  I couldn't really find the Oracle's version of MySQL source (and I didn't really bother digging for it), but found `twitter`'s version in github.  Have a look at `https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/`, `sql/sql_select.cc` `JOIN::prepare` between lines 498 and 554 and `setup_wild` at line 7846 in `sql/sql_base.cc`.

Answer (score 5):

Pros:

- when you really need all the columns, it's shorter to write `select *`

Cons:

- most of the time, you don't need all the columns, but only some of them. It's more efficient to only retrieve what you want
- you have no guarantee of the order of the retrieved columns (or at least, the order is not obvious from the query), which forbids accessing columns by index (only by name). But the names are also far from obvious
- when joining multiple tables having potentially columns with the same name, you can define aliases for these columns